# CI multiple like condition activerecord

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, sql-like

I have the following Active Record query.

```
public function select_kd_barang_detail($kd = null) {
    $this->db->select("a.no_barang, a.kd_barang, b.jenis, c.ukuran, d.merk, e.nama_barang");
    $this->db->from("t_barang_detail a, t_barang_jenis b, t_barang_ukuran c, t_barang_merk d, t_barang e");
    $where = "a.jenis = b.id_jenis AND a.ukuran = c.id_ukuran AND a.merk = d.id_merk AND a.kd_barang = e.kd_barang";
    $this->db->where($where);
    if ($kd != null) {
        $this->db->like("a.kd_barang", $kd);
        $this->db->or_like("e.nama_barang", $kd);
    }

    return $this->db->get();
}
```

and i have been to try using

```
$this->db-where("(a.kd_barang LIKE $kd OR e.nama_barang LIKE $kd)");
```

and

```
$this->db->or_like(array('a.kd_barang' => $kd, 'e.nama_barang' => $kd));
```

but the result always wrong.

Answer (score 1):

this problem is solved.

I'm using this code

```
$this->db->where("(a.kd_barang LIKE '%$kd%' OR e.nama_barang LIKE '%$kd%')");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make this working like this:

```
if ($kd != null) {
        $this->db->or_where("(a.kd_barang LIKE '$kd' OR e.nama_barang LIKE '$kd')");
    }
```

Comment: that work, but result still wrong.
i have been try to test the qury in phpmyadmin, 
the result is true.

Comment: May be there is a mistake in your query.